# How to avoid multiple method overriding in C#?

Tags: c#

I have a DLL, that we bought and I can't access its source. However, for the problem that I'm now facing, I've been told that I must inherit from a class in the DLL, and override one of its methods.

I tried it and it works quite well, as expected. My problem now is that I have quite a few classes where I need to do the same thing, and don't want to repeat the same code so many times. Although all of those classes inherit from the same DLL class, it doesn't look good to me to write the same code in all of them.
This is the code for one class:

```
public class MyClass : DllClass
{
    protected override void MethodFromDll()
    {
       //here I inserted my code and it works ok
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Why not create an abstract class which derives from `DllClass` and override the method there, then derive your other classes from that?

```
public abstract class MyClassBase : DllClass
{
    protected override void MethodFromDll()
    {
       //here I inserted my code and it works ok
    }
}

...

public class MyClass : MyClassBase
{
    // Whatever else you need
}
```

That's assuming you need inheritance here in the first place - do you definitely need to have multiple derived classes, or could you have lots of classes which use `MyClass` by composition instead?

Comment: Thanks Jon,
First, for your question if I need multiple derived classes, the answer is yes. I must do it this way. That's the way we work with this DLL.
As for your solution, it looks clear. However, I'm afraid of losing functionality by that solution.
For example, now I have about 5 classes that will need to inherit from that abstract class. Let's say that in the future two of them (Class1 and Class2) will need to inherit from a different new abstract class. But not only this, in addition to Class1 and Class2 I'll need Class20 and Class21 to inherit from the same new abstract class.
Advice?